# Exception raised while inserting values into Azure COSMOS DB for MongDB API : Document does not contain shard key

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I have created a database in Azure: Azure Cosmos DB.

While creating the db, I have selected the Resource Group, given Account Name, API :  selected `Azure COSMOS DB for MongDB API and given rest of the required details and created the DB account.

Once the DB account is created , I have added a a DB `abc-test` in it and added a collection `abc-test-col`. While creating the collection I have given shard key as `id`.

Now I have created a console application to test the connectivity and write some value into the database.This is the code I have written.

```
class Program
    {
        static  void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Start Execution");
                Program p = new Program();

                IMongoCollection<CollectionData> collection = p.GetCollection();

                CollectionData cd = new CollectionData();
                cd.id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                cd.Value = 100;


                Task insertjob = collection.InsertOneAsync(cd);
                insertjob.Wait(); // exception raised here

                Console.WriteLine("Inserted data");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception : " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private IMongoCollection<CollectionData> GetCollection()
        {
            try
            {
                string mongDBName = "abc-test";
                IMongoDatabase database;
                string collectionName = "abc-test-col";

                string connectionString = "Connection String"; // Copied the primary connection string.
                MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.FromUrl(
                  new MongoUrl(connectionString)
                );
                settings.SslSettings =
                  new SslSettings() { EnabledSslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 };
                var mongoClient = new MongoClient(settings);

                database = mongoClient.GetDatabase(mongDBName);

                return database.GetCollection<CollectionData>(collectionName);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

When I run this , I'm getting an exception

> One or more errors occurred. (Command insert failed: document does not
>   contain shard key.)

I have added `id` in my CollectionData, but still it is giving this exception.
Any help as to why this is throwing this error.Am I missing something

Any help in this matter will be so helpful.

Comment: Did you create the collection through the Azure Portal? Was the collection created with Azure CLI or the visual user interface?

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta I created from Azure portal.

Comment: And did you use `az cli` on the Azure Portal? I saw people running into this issue while using `az cli`.

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta , No didn't use any commands. I have done it manually.